# Can nice() be used to round day in d3 date

Tags: d3.js

Why isn't this rounding the day of the date?

```
d3.time.scale().domain(domain).range(range).nice(d3.time.day);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted will extend the scale in both directions to the nearest day boundary. `.nice()` does not mean that output value will be rounded.

Comment: Is it possible to get whole numbers in the date only?

Comment: You have to round the date yourself, but yes, certainly.